# How to I find what is hiding an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, gallery

I'm having a problem where when the page is loaded, a div element becomes hidden. Developer Tools in Chrome tells me "element.style" is setting "display: none"

It's not in my css anywhere to display none. I can't find in either of the related javascript files anything that would hide the element.

I'm totally lost as to why its hidden.

The jquery plugin I'm using is called Supersized.

Edit:
Feel free to check out the page I'm working on: http://www.gingereventsmpls.com/gallery2.html

If you inspect the html, the element that gets hidden is at the end of this hierarchy: body->div"controls-wrapper"->div"controls"->div"tray-button"

"#tray-button" is what is getting display:none attached to it somehow.

Comment: I didn't see #tray-button ......

Comment: @C-Link check `hyperlink` .

Comment: still unable to see where is it I also searched #tray but not found...

Comment: <a id="tray-button" style="display: none;"><img id="tray-arrow" src="images/supersize/button-tray-up.png"></a>

Naturally you won't be able to search for an id using #id You'll have to search for just "tray-button"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you'd like the root cause of your problem, it's the following lines (found in supersized3.shutter.js):

```
        $(vars.tray_button).toggle(function(){
            $(vars.thumb_tray).stop().animate({bottom : 0, avoidTransforms : true}, 300 );
            if ($(vars.tray_arrow).attr('src')) $(vars.tray_arrow).attr("src", vars.image_path + "button-tray-down.png");
            return false;
        }, function() {
            $(vars.thumb_tray).stop().animate({bottom : -$(vars.thumb_tray).height(), avoidTransforms : true}, 300 );
            if ($(vars.tray_arrow).attr('src')) $(vars.tray_arrow).attr("src", vars.image_path + "button-tray-up.png");
            return false;
        });
```

It's attempting to use the [event-based toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), but unfortunately that version of the toggle function was deprecated as of JQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9 (you're using 1.9). So what's actually happening is [THIS toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function is being called, which simply toggles whether or not the div is hidden or shown.

You can choose to either downgrade to JQuery 1.8 or lower, or rewrite the part of the plugin that is relying on the old event-based toggle function.

Hope this helps!

Edit: I've rewritten the above part of the plugin to be compatible with 1.9 in the below code, please let me know if this works, I haven't tested:

```
$(vars.tray_button).on('click',function(){
    var self=$(this)
    self.data('toggle',!self.data('toggle'))
    if(self.data('toggle')) {
        $(vars.thumb_tray).stop().animate({bottom : 0, avoidTransforms : true}, 300 );
        if ($(vars.tray_arrow).attr('src')) $(vars.tray_arrow).attr("src", vars.image_path + "button-tray-down.png");
    } else {
        $(vars.thumb_tray).stop().animate({bottom : -$(vars.thumb_tray).height(), avoidTransforms : true}, 300 );
        if ($(vars.tray_arrow).attr('src')) $(vars.tray_arrow).attr("src", vars.image_path + "button-tray-up.png");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @Great very much appreciable.

Answer (score -1):

Or by jquery like this:

```
    $('#tray-button').removeAttr('style');
```